# Best way to prevent view counts from being abused

Tags: python, cookies, redis, counter

I'm currently using Redis to store a view count for each time a page is loaded. It's working fantastic but my only worry is that it will be abused. When a user is logged in on my site, the view counter will only update if they have not viewed the thread yet (again, tracked by Redis) so that abuse is negated.

My problem is with users I don't have an account for. If I were to let the view count be updated every time the page is loaded if someone created some content they could just log out and refresh the page as many times as they wanted to get their view count up. My first thought was identify every non-account user through a session cookie (I already track users logged in through a session cookie) but if someone cleared that cookie, it would be rendered useless again. Another thought is an IP address but through dynamic IP addresses it wouldn't be very reliable either.

So my question is, what is the most reliable way to track a view count from an unknown user?

Comment: You can générate a cookie based on the user ip / login. This way an authenticated user will always have the same cookie. You may missing some users if they are more than one behind an ip adress md5(salt + user|anon + ip)

Comment: Yeah, seems like that's the best tradeoff for simplicity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of tracking view counts!

Ill let you in on a couple of trade secrets.

What you want is probably a pixel tracker.

A pixel tracker is a service that serves a 1x1 pixel that does nothing except log the time that it is requested. So if you say you want to track someone visiting a thread, you could, make a sha512 hash of the thread name, `sha512(thread_name)` and get a hash. Then with this hash request a pixel from your webserver as follows

```
/px/<sha512hash>.gif
```

Then you can insert this request into a database, next time that page is rendered, you sha512 the title, you request that pixel, then you realise that this user has already been served a pixel for this title. You ignore the request, you do not increment the view counter.

Comment: @gawel had a good answer. I'd rather tradeoff simplicity for 100% accuracy. Curious though, wouldn't this rely on the browser caching the .gif?

Comment: @d0ctor you log the request for the resource server side.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting it... sorry haha. I log the request for the resource, let's say the handler is /viewcount. The SHA-512 hash, say from passlib, will be random each time. Even if I make it static each time, that will only allow one guest to increment the counter. How can I track it per-guest if an IP address is not reliable? The only thing I see workable is just a random cookie for each guest and hoping that they don't clear it.

Comment: You hash the title name